# spyder - python IDE uft8 encoding loading issue

Tags: python, spyder

I am unable to get spyder to load. I am running windows 7, 64 bit.

I have installed  Anaconda-2.3.0 64 bit and have attempted to run the bundled spyder.
I have also tried the latest separate spyder build and encountered the exact same issue.

When running spyder via cmd I recieve the following error message:
"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\scripts\spyder", line 2, in <module>
    from spyderlib import start_app
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\start_app.py", line 13, in <modu
le>
    from spyderlib.config import CONF
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\config.py", line 718, in <module
>
    subfolder=SUBFOLDER, backup=True, raw_mode=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\userconfig.py", line 215, in __i
nit__
    self.load_from_ini()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\userconfig.py", line 260, in loa
d_from_ini
    self.readfp(configfile)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 324, in readfp
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 479, in _read
    line = fp.readline()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py", line 678, in readline
    return self.reader.readline(size)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py", line 533, in readline
    data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py", line 480, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 59: invalid
continuation byte
```

"
Is there some way to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Figured it out.
uninstall/reinstall anaconda.
delete Libraries\Documents.spyder2 folder
Run spyder. Wait a long time. spyder loads.
yay.